# Why can't we close some tags for cross site scripting purposes?

Tags: xss, html

There's a webstore that i am trying to find a XSS vulnerability for BUG BOUNTY.
On that store is a search bar that i can send anything

```
https://www.examplestore.com/blog/?s=</title><script>alert(1);</script>
```

But even if i use `</title>` for trying to break it, the result gets into:

```
<title>You searched for </title><script>alert(1);</script> - Blabla's Store </title>
```

it seems the `</title>` i provided is acting like 'string', why its not able to close the title tag? i mean.. its definetly a closing tag! can anyone explain me what is going on ?

Comment: You have simply not found a vulnerability!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the XSS isn't firing, the problem is that you're looking at the processed HTML, not the raw page source. This usually happens if you're using the browser developer tools - rather than the "view page source" feature, or an intercepting proxy - to examine the HTML. You *can* get the raw HTML from the dev console using the `innerHTML` property of elements.

For example, if you right-click on your example text in the question and inspect it in the dev tools, it'll look like `<title>You searched for </title><script>alert(1);</script> - Blabla's Store </title>`. However, if you use the developer console to request `document.body.innerHTML.match(/<code>.*?alert.*?<\/code>/)` - which runs a regular expression match on the HTML of the body of this page, selecting the first element that starts with `<code>`, contains `alert`, and ends with `</code>` (`<code>` being how StackExchange markdown renders content within ` characters) - you'll get instead `"<code>&lt;title&gt;You searched for &lt;/title&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(1);&lt;/script&gt; - Blabla's Store &lt;/title&gt;</code>"`.

The `innerHTML` property has shown that, even though the dev tools inspector makes it look like the page contains a `<script>` substring, the angle brackets were escaped and it actually only contains `&lt;script&gt;` and similar. If you run the same query on your actual target site - using `document.head.innerHTML.match(/<title>.*<\/title>/)` since you're instead grabbing the full title of the page from its header - you'll probably see the same escaping on your injected text.

The site is either encoding the `<` characters as `&lt;` on the server, or is using the `innerText`/`textContent` property rather than the `innerHTML` property to set the title in Javascript. `innerText` and `textContent` automatically encode HTML metacharacters such as `<`. In other words, **this insertion point is not vulnerable**. There might be XSS elsewhere on the site, but the title appears to be reflecting user input in a safe way.